# How to get the list of pending changes after 'get specific version'

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs

My problem is like this: I wrongly checked in some files, including some edits and adds. Let's assume the changeset nummber is 0. I rolled back the changeset quickly, and checked in the new pending changes (deletes mainly), then I checked in again to roll back things on TFS. The changeset number is 1.

Now I want to get my files back. I've done a 'get specific version' of version 0. I've got my files back, but now my list of pending changes is lost. Now if I have a new 'get', all my files will be lost again. How can I get the list of pending changes back? Do I have to manually modify and add the files?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no answer...

The answer of my colleagues: there's no way. You have to redo things manually.

Answer (score 0):

Rollback changeset #1.  This will "pend" all of your adds/edits.  Fix whatever problem caused you to roll it back in the first place, then check it in.

This is a common scenario, and though it seems weird, rolling back the rollback is the proper approach.